# Session cookies are not being marked "secure" in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, session, tomcat, cookies

I have tried a few different ways to get session cookies to have the "secure" flag set, but haven't been able to get it to work. Here are the things I've tried so far:

#### 1. Use  in `web.xml`

The standard way to configure the "secure" cookie attribute for a session cookie is to apply the following configuration in `web.xml` -- but this did not work as it is supported only by Tomcat versions above 7.

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
    <secure>true</secure>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

#### 2. Set `secure="true"` in `server.xml` `<Connector>`

I tried a few different connector options as below but none of them helped:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https"
  secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

#### 3. Manually re-write the cookie

I added the following code in a filter to rewrite the JSESSIONID value by setting it as a custom header. However I still do not see the secure attribute in my cookie.

```
String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; secure");
```

I think I'm out of options. What can I do to get my session cookies flagged as "secure"?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for you in Tomcat 6 because the `<cookie-config>` configuration attributes in `web.xml` were added in Servlet Spec 3.0, and Tomcat 6 only supports Servlet Spec 2.5. So if you want to use `<cookie-config>`, you're going to have to upgrade. (You should probably upgrade, anyway. Tomcat 6 is pretty much in maintenance mode at this point, and Tomcat 8 has been stable for quite some time.)

In `server.xml`, setting `secure="true"` changes nothing, since a TLS connector will already have `secure="true"` set by default.

You didn't mention exactly what version of Tomcat 6 you are running, but Tomcat will in fact set the "secure" flag for cookies automatically if the connection was secure when the cookie was created.

My guess is that your session cookies are being created before the user is using a secured connection. When that happens, the session cookie needs to stay "non-secure" otherwise the session might not work.

You should arrange for your users to start using TLS before a session is created, and you should get "secure" session cookies.

Comment: I am using tomcat version 6.0.37.

Comment: Can you re-try your tests with the latest Tomcat 6.0.44?

Answer (score 0):

The #2 solution from the question (*secure="true*") actually works.

Here's what I'm using on tomcat 6.0.35:

```
    <Connector port="8091"
            secure="true" 
            acceptCount="25" 
            connectionTimeout="20000" 
            disableUploadTimeout="true" 
            backlog="25" 
            maxSpareThreads="75" 
            maxThreads="1024" 
            minSpareThreads="25" 
            emptySessionPath="true"
            maxPostSize="4194304"
            maxParameterCount="20000"
```

I noticed that it works regardless of SSL being enabled on the Connector.